# How to use FlickityService to control the start / stop of player

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, flickity

I am developing a photo slideshow using the Angular Flickity directive. I can use FlickityService to call next and previous function to move the slide to the next and previous slide. But how can I control the start and stop of the player although Flickity api has stopPlay and startPlayer?

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="previous()">Previous </button>
 <button ng-click="next()">Next </button>
 <button ng-click="play()">Play </button>
 <button ng-click="stop()">Stop </button>
<div class="gallery-container">
      <div class="gallery-slides"
            bc-flickity="{{ flickityOptions }}"
            bc-flickity-id="demoId1">
          <div class="gallery-slide" ng-repeat="slide in photoList track by $index">
                <img ng-src="{{slide}}"  />
           </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In my angular controller, I have the following functions:

```
$scope.FlickityService = FlickityService; 

$scope.next = function () {
   $scope.FlickityService.next("demoId1", true);
}
$scope.previous = function () {
   $scope.FlickityService.previous("demoId1", true);
}
 $scope.stop = function () {
   // ???
}
 $scope.start = function () {
   // ???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can use the following code instead of using FlickityService to call the Flickity Api to start and stop the player.

```
$scope.start = function () {
   var flkty = Flickity.data($('.gallery-slides')[0]);
   flkty.playPlayer();
}
$scope.stop = function () {
   var flkty = Flickity.data($('.gallery-slides')[0]);
   flkty.stopPlayer();
}
```